# Regular grammar, output language

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I can't understand which language does this grammar represent.

L3 = L (G) where G is the grammar defined as G = <Vn, Vt, S, P>, with Vn = {S}, Vt = {0,1} and P the set of productions $S→λ|1S0|0S1|SS$

Comment: I guess $\lambda$ is another symbol for $\epsilon$, i.e the empty string?

Comment: @b00nheT yes lambda is empty string.

Comment: I don't understand for example, what $0S1$ generates.

Comment: It's one of the rules of the grammar: it means that your string will start with 0 then you can again use any of the rules of S and it will end with a 1

Comment: Oh, so 010 could be a string that is in the language?

Comment: No, it's impossible to obtain that string. But 10 and 01 will, as well as 1100 and 1010 and 00011101

Comment: Which string does $SS$ then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130899/discussion-between-b00n-het-and-rustik-ideas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This grammar represent the language of all strings with the same number of 0's and 1's.

To prove it notice that any production rule produces such a string. Now argue the converse by taking any string with the same number of 0s and 1s and deduce how it can be constructed using such rules.